# triggering a function on failed assertion

Tags: python, assert

Is there a way to trigger a function if an assertion fails?

I am thinking about unittest at the moment but could change test framework if need be.

I would like to take a screenshot when an assertion fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
try:
   assert something == something_else
except AssertionError:
   take_screenshot()
```

is one way you could do it.

In some cases you might want to use a decorator:

```
>>> def assertd(function):
        def _f(*args):
            try:
                return function(*args)
            except AssertionError:
                takescreenshot()
        return _f

>>> @assertd
def f(x, y):
    assert x > 0
    return x + y

>>> f(1, 2)
3
>>> f(5, 6)
11
>>> f(-7, 8)
<Screenshot taken>
```

Comment: thanks that should do what i need

Comment: @Calum No problem! If this answer helped you it would be good to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it at some point.